# How do I Use re() in Python and Return Capture Groups within an "If" Statement?

Tags: python, regex

Although I've been using Perl for many years, I've always had trouble with anything more than fairly basic use of Regular Expresions in the language.  This is
only a worse situation now, as I'm trying to learn Python... and the use of re() is even more unclear to me.

I'm trying to check for a match if a substring is in a string, using re()
and also am using capture groups to extract some info from the matching process.  However, I can't get things to work in a couple of
contexts; when using a re() call and assigning the returned values all
within an "if" statement.. and how to handle the situation when .groups items are not defined
in the match objects (when a match is not made).

So, what follows are examples of what I'm trying to do coded in Perl and Python, with their respective outputs.

I'd appreciate any pointers on how I might better approach the problem using Python.

Perl Code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($idx, $dvalue);

while (my $rec = <DATA>) {
   chomp($rec);
   if ( ($idx, $dvalue) = ($rec =~ /^XA([0-9]+)=(.*?)!/) ) {
      printf("  Matched:\n");
      printf("    rec: >%s<\n", $rec);
      printf("    index = >%s<  value = >%s<\n", $idx, $dvalue);

   } elsif ( ($idx, $dvalue) = ($rec =~ /^PZ([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!/) ) {
      printf("  Matched:\n");
      printf("    rec: >%s<\n", $rec);
      printf("    index = >%s<  value = >%s<\n", $idx, $dvalue);

   } else {
      printf("\n  Unknown Record format, \\%s\\\n\n", $rec);

   }
}
close(DATA);

exit(0)      

__DATA__
DUD=ABC!QUEUE=D23!
XA32=7!P^=32!
PZ112=123^!PQ=ABC!
```

Perl Output:

```
  Unknown Record format, \DUD=ABC!QUEUE=D23!\

  Matched:
    rec: >XA32=7!P^=32!<
    index = >32<  value = >7<
  Matched:
    rec: >PZ112=123^!PQ=ABC!<
    index = >112<  value = >123^<
```

Python Code:

```python
import re

string = 'XA32=7!P^=32!'

with open('data.dat', 'r') as fh:
   for rec in fh:
      orec = '    rec: >' + rec.rstrip('\n') + '<'
      print(orec)

      # always using 'string' at least lets this program run          
      (index, dvalue) = re.search(r'^XA([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!', string).groups()

      # The following works when there is a match... but fails with an error when
      # a match is NOT found, viz:-
      # ...    
      #     (index, dvalue) = re.search(r'^XA([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!', rec).groups()
      #
      #   Traceback (most recent call last):
      #     File "T:\tmp\a.py", line 13, in <module>
      #       (index, dvalue) = re.search(r'^XA([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!', rec).groups()
      #   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
      #

      buf = '    index = >' + index + '<' + '  value = >' + dvalue + '<'     
      print(buf)

exit(0)
```

data.dat contents:

```
DUD=ABC!QUEUE=D23!
XA32=7!P^=32!
PZ112=123^!PQ=ABC!
```

Python Output:

```
    rec: >DUD=ABC!QUEUE=D23!<
    index = >32<  value = >7<
    rec: >XA32=7!P^=32!<
    index = >32<  value = >7<
    rec: >PZ112=123^!PQ=ABC!<
    index = >32<  value = >7<
```

**Another development:** Some more code to help me understand this better...  but I'm unsure about when/how to use the `match.group()` or `match.groups()` ...

Python Code:

```
import re

rec = 'XA22=11^!S^=64!ABC=0,0!PX=0!SP=12B!'
print("rec = >{}<".format(rec))

# ----

index = 0 ; dvalue = 0 ; x = 0 
match = re.match(r'XA([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!(.*?)!', rec) 
if match:
   (index, dvalue, x) = match.groups()
   print("3 ():  index = >{}< value = >{}< x = >{}<".format(index, dvalue, x))

# ----

index = 0 ; dvalue = 0 ; x = 0 
match = re.match(r'XA([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!', rec) 
if match:
   (index, dvalue) = match.groups()
   print("2 ():  index = >{}< value = >{}< x = >{}<".format(index, dvalue, x))

# ----

index = 0 ; dvalue = 0 ; x = 0 
match = re.match(r'XA([0-9]+)=', rec) 
if match:
    #(index) = match.groups()  # Why doesn't this work like above examples!?
   (index, ) = match.groups()  # ...and yet this works!?
                               # Does match.groups ALWAYS returns a tuple!?
   #(index) = match.group(1)    # This also works; 0 = entire matched string?
   print("1 ():  index = >{}< value = >{}< x = >{}<".format(index, dvalue, x))

# ----

index = 0 ; dvalue = 0 ; x = 0 
match = re.search(r'S\^=([0-9]+)!', rec) 
if match:
   (index, ) = match.groups()  # Returns tuple(?!)
   print("1 ():  index = >{}< value = >{}< x = >{}<".format(index, dvalue, x))
```

Again, I'd appreciate any thoughts on which is the 'preferred' way.. or if there's another way to deal with the groups.

Comment: If you want to learn about regular expressions I would recommend reading [Jeffrey Friedl - Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do).

Comment: @StefanBecker I know the Friedl book well.. but find it difficult to wade through (much like O'Reilly's 'Programming Python'.. *Whew!*).  I more often refer to [Regular Expression Cookbook, by Goyvaerts & Levithan.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023630.do).

Comment: It's best if you say what you want to accomplish rather than providing it in another language. (Unless, of course, the problem is understanding the Perl code, in which case that should be your question.) Since this question has no more to do with Perl than English, I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for a match first, then use the groups. I.e.

- compile the regexes (optional for most cases nowadays, according to the documentation)
- apply each regex to the string to generate a match object

  - `match()` only matches at the beginning of a string, i.e. with an implicit `^` anchor
  - `search()` matches anywhere in the string
- check if the match object is valid

  - extract the groups
  - skip to next loop iteration

```python
# works with Python 2 and Python 3
import re

with open('dummy.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for rec in fh:
        orec = '    rec: >' + rec.rstrip('\n') + '<'
        print(orec)

        match = re.match(r'XA([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!', rec)
        if match:
            (index, dvalue) = match.groups()
            print("    index = >{}<  value = >{}<".format(index, dvalue))
            continue

        match = re.match(r'PZ([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!', rec)
        if match:
            (index, dvalue) = match.groups()
            print("    index = >{}<  value = >{}<".format(index, dvalue))
            continue

        print("    Unknown Record format")
```

Output:

```
$ python dummy.py
    rec: >DUD=ABC!QUEUE=D23!<
    Unknown Record format
    rec: >XA32=7!P^=32!<
    index = >32<  value = >7<
    rec: >PZ112=123^!PQ=ABC!<
    index = >112<  value = >123^<
```

---

But I'm wondering why you don't simplify your Perl & Python code to just use a single regex instead? E.g.:

```python
match = re.match(r'(?:XA|PZ)([0-9]+)=(.*?[^#])!', rec)
if match:
    (index, dvalue) = match.groups()
    print("    index = >{}<  value = >{}<".format(index, dvalue))
else:
    print("    Unknown Record format")
```

Comment: Some great ideas there, thanks.  In the 'real' program, the 'XA', 'PZ', etc number around 10 items... and the actions to be performed vary with each 'tag', hence the effective 'switch' action...  but a good thought.